# Does Core Motion in watchOS 2 allow access to the gyroscope?

Tags: ios, accelerometer, watchkit, gyroscope, core-motion

I see accelerometer mentioned but nothing of gyroscope access? can any one can help me out on this

Answer (score 1):

According to this [github project](https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler) the gyroscope is not (yet?) available on watchOS 2.